# Partial derivatives of a 3D function formula

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

We can use forward, backward or central difference formula to calculate the partial derivatives of a 1D (x) or 2D (x,y) function. What will be the formula using any of the methods to calculate the derivative of a 3D (x,y,z) function?

Like for 2D (x,y) function, the forward difference formula is -

[image]

Comment: Where's the "centering" in the above definition?

Comment: My bad. It is forward difference formula. I corrected it. @RiccardoCeccon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by 2D central differentiation formula you mean:

$f_x(x,y)=$lim$_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h/2,y)-f(x-h/2,y)}{h}.$

Now, for 3D functions there are no differences:

$f_x(x,y,z)=$lim$_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h/2,y,z)-f(x-h/2,y,z)}{h},$ and likewise for $f_y$ and $f_z.$

If you have other questions ask me, I don't know if this was your doubt precisely, maybe you were asking a different thing.